# Spring default login page not found

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, default

Here is my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){ return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); }
```

I expected to see the default login page at /login, but I got 404 error. What may be wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/hellomvc-javaconfig.html#registering-spring-security-with-the-war

I did not declare required `MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` class.

Comment: I have the same problem. The link above doesn't work any more. Could you advise please?

Comment: @Vojtech link fixed